Unable to View Updated Model with Same Name in Autodesk Platform Services (APS) Viewer
I am uploading a STEP file to an Autodesk Platform Services (APS) bucket and translating it to SVF for viewing in the APS Viewer.
Later, I want to upload a different model with the same name. To achieve this, I:

Deleted the manifest of the original model using the API:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/manifest
Deleted the model itself using the API:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey
Uploaded a new model with the same name.

The new model is successfully uploaded and translated, but it does not appear in the Viewer.
I am using the Visual Studio Code extension for uploading and translating the model. Can anyone help me understand why the new model is not visible in the Viewer and how I can fix this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help!

You still need to reload the model in the viewer after the model has been updated. Also please add a relevant code snippet of the viewer implementation

May I suggest you try testing this model on a web APS viewer to see if you pick anything related to viewer libraries from front-end on console: You may try:

https://autodesk-platform-services.github.io/aps-tutorial-postman/display_svf2.html
https://viewer.autodesk.com/

I have tried the steps you have provided on the APS VS code extension and both models loaded okay. I am not sure of what your second model entails but if the same issue persists, please reach out to aps.help@autodesk.com via email and we may require your sample model.

Hi Carol,
I tested this on the web APS Viewer and encountered the same issue. The problem arises specifically when I upload a STEP model to the viewer, delete its manifest, and then delete the model itself. If I later upload a different STEP model with the same name and then try to see it in APS viewer then the viewer is blank.
